# Not being able to make following ng-on-click-outside directive work on two elements on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have written a ng-on-click-outside directive which I am using to close menus on a page when clicked outside of that menu. It doesn't behave as expected when applied to multiple elemnts on same page. Here's the directive

```
.directive('ngOnClickOutside', ['$window', function ($window) {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var w = angular.element($window);
            var click_handler = function (e) {
                if (!element.has(e.target).length && !element.is(e.target)){
                    if(attrs.ngDisallowOnClickOutsideIf){
                        if(!$(attrs.ngDisallowOnClickOutsideIf).is(e.target) && !$(attrs.ngDisallowOnClickOutsideIf).children().is(e.target)){
                            scope.$eval(attrs.ngOnClickOutside);
                            scope.$apply();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        scope.$eval(attrs.ngOnClickOutside);
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                }
            };
            w.bind('click', click_handler);
        };
    }])
```

here `attrs.ngOnClickOutside` is the action to be performed when clicked outside of the menu.
So I basically I need to distinguish between the elements some how so that the action of other element doesn't get applied. Any ideas how I could do that?

If I use isolate scope in this directive then the isolate scope doesn't contain the function on which eval should work on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an isolate scope. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

That will allow your directives to not interfere with each other when there are  more than one on a page. Adding `scope: {}` to your directive will accomplish this.

```
<div id="1" directive-with-isolate-scope></div>
```

can't interfere with

```
<div id="2" directive-with-isolate-scope></div>
```

Comment: Hey @Yatrix what you say makes sense and I tried that but now `scope.$eval(attrs.ngOnClickOutside);` is not getting applied.